# Duplicate entries while calculating Mean in Group By in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `mydata`:

```
PC1             sector
0.0002187305    Utilities
0.0002369591    Financials
0.0003339332    Health Care
0.0006809497    Financials
0.0004811478    Consumer Staples
0.0015884347    Consumer Staples
0.0004643183    Consumer Discretionary
0.0001093301    Energy
0.0002807079    Consumer Staples
0.0003112860    Health Care
0.0002418978    Information Technology
```

I am trying to obtain the Mean of PC1 column grouped by the Sector category.
I tried the following code:

Attempt 1

```
data.plot2 <- ddply(mydata,~sector, summarise, mean=mean(as.numeric(as.character(PC1))))
```

Both give me the following output:

```
Consumer Discretionary  0.0004643183
Consumer Staples        0.0015884347
Consumer Staples        0.0003809279
Energy                  0.0001093301
Financials              0.0004589544
Health Care             0.0003226096
Information Technology  0.0002418978
Utilities               0.0002187305
```

The `str(mydata)` gives me the following:

```
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ PC1   : num  0.000219 0.000237 0.000334 0.000681 0.000481 ...
 $ sector: Factor w/ 21 levels "Consumer ...
```

Could someone highlight what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You very likely have trailing white space or something similar in one of those. What is the full output of `levels(mydata$sector)`?

Comment: Yes you are right. There is a trailing space.

Comment: You can write it yourself easily, but in the `stringr` package there is a `str_trim` function to remove leading and trailing whitespace. you'll have to re-factor that column though.

Comment: I trimmed the sector. Now the output looks fine! Thanks!